# PHP - curl - How to create API source to use CURLOPT_USERPWD function

Tags: php, api, curl

curl has the following function CURLOPT_USERPWD - How should I design my api to allow this function to work?

I'm asking to learn out of curiosity. Unfortunately I couldn't find any literature on this.

Comment: warning, if you go this route then your api won't be able to support the `:` character in the username/password

Comment: `CURLOPT_USERPWD` is an option, not a function. Please explain what are you trying to achieve, show what you have tried and explain how that failed. As currently written, the question doesn't make any sense

Answer (score 0):

it uses http basic auth, read this article: http://php.net/manual/en/features.http-auth.php

```
<?php
if (!isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'])) {
    header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="My Realm"');
    header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
    echo 'Text to send if user hits Cancel button';
    exit;
} else {
    echo "<p>Hello {$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']}.</p>";
    echo "<p>You entered {$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']} as your password.</p>";
}
```